# Unable to add new input on AngularJS with Slim REST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, slim

I am unable to add a new item using a Slim PHP Rest Service and Angular JS, how do I get it to add to the database?

Below is my code: 
Slim REST Service Code 
//function to add an individual location

```
function AddLocation()
{  
   $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance(); 

   //
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
   $location = json_decode($request->getBody()); 
   $sql = "INSERT INTO locations (location_title, location_latitude, location_longitude') VALUES (:location_title, :location_latitude, :location_longitude)"; 
   // 
    try { 
      $db =  conn_db(); 
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
      $stmt->bindParam("location_title", $location->location_title);
        $stmt->bindParam("location_latitude", $location->location_latitude); 
        $stmt->bindParam("location_longitude", $location->location_longitude); 


        $stmt->execute();
        $location->location_id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($location); 

    } catch (PDEOxception $e) { 

        echo 'Error';   
    } 

}
```

Angular JS Code

```
//CONTROLLER == add new page 
    countryApp.controller('AddNew', function($scope, $http, $location) { 

        $scope.master = {}; 
        $scope.activePath = null; 

        $scope.add_new = function(location, AddNewForm) { 
            $http.post('http://localhost/slimtest2/add_location', location).success(function() { 
                $scope.reset(); 
                $scope.activePath = $location.path('/'); 

            }); 

            $scope.reset = function() { 
               $scope.location = angular.copy($scope.master);  
            }; 

            $scope.reset(); 
        }; 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
...
$app->post('/products', function() use ($app) { 
    $data = json_decode($app->request->getBody());
    $mandatory = array('name');

    global $db;
    $rows = $db->insert("products", $data, $mandatory);
    if($rows["status"] == "success")
        $rows["message"] = "Product added successfully.";
    echoResponse(200, $rows);
});
function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    global $app;
    $app->status($status_code);
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

$app->run();
```

Angular code call the fuction

```
$scope.saveProduct = function (product) {
...
Products.post('products', product).then(function (result) {
  if (result.status != 'error') {

    console.log(result);


    var x = angular.copy(product);
    x.save = 'insert';
    x.id = result.data;
    $modalInstance.close(x);
  } else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
...
```

and template

```
 <form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>

<form-element label="NAME" mod="product">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="NAME" ng-model="product.name" ng-disabled="product.id" focus/>
</form-element>

<form-element label="DESCRIPTION" mod="product">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="DESCRIPTION" ng-model="product.description">{{product.description}}</textarea>
</form-element>
...
<button ng-click="saveProduct(product);"
        ng-disabled="product_form.$invalid || enableUpdate"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        type="submit">
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>{{buttonText}}
</button>
```

you have good example for angular part:
[Building a Basic CRUD Application Using AngularJS and Slim PHP framework (Part 1)](http://www.blog.iamaronbarbosa.com/building-a-basic-crud-application-using-angularjs-and-slim-php-framework-part-1/) 
and great example for the slim part [RESTful services with jQuery, PHP and the Slim Framework](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/)

I hope, I helped you.